# Error when uninstalling composite c1 blog package

Tags: azure, c1-cms

**Problem**

- I setup a composite c1 website on `Azure` using the app market place.
- I installed the blog package some time ago but never used it.
- I would like to remove the package but when I try to do so, I receive an error stating that the `Entries.xml` file can not be located and the uninstall exits.
- I have manually created the `Entries.xml` file in my system folder, in the correct place, but I still get the same message.

**Question**

How can I uninstall this package that is failing to uninstall?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Inna on codeplex for this answer

Hi, 
Please note that Composite C1 was moved to https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-CMS 
Composite C1 Packages - https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-Packages 
I reported the Blog package issue here - https://github.com/Orckestra/C1-Packages/issues/15

Please try next workaround how to delete the package from the console:

1) make sure that package files are deleted form the site folder . I think that all files were deleted when you was trying to uninstall package first time, just re-check, if not, then delete.:

- locate folder \App_Data\Composite\Packages\303b7865-055b-4fe7-a429-907b32bb6776
- locate file uninstall.xml
- make sure that files listed in node  deleted from the site folder.
- go to Data perspective -> Global Datatypes and make sure that datatypes with namespace "Composite.Community.Blog" deleted.
- go to Layout perspective -> Page Types and make sure that Blog pagetype is deleted.

2) Delete folder \App_Data\Composite\Packages\303b7865-055b-4fe7-a429-907b32bb6776